# Updating multiple values to sql table using Datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, sql-update

I am having a SQL table cost(sno,comp_name,sellingprice).
I need to develop an interface for entering values of sellingprice, where sno and comp_name are static values.
I set default value for sellingprice as 1.

For this purpose I used a Datagridview by choosing datasource and then the COST table contents to be displayed in the Datagridview.

Finally if user enters/updates values in the sellingprice column, then the changes need to be reflected in the Database.

Can somebody please help me in achieving this..
Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve what you're asking for. The easiest way is using [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) class.

There are at least 2 known to me ways to create Update/Insert/.. commands:

- automatic (Adapater generates SQL itself)
- manual    (You do it in a way you like it)

For concrete and complete example of different patterns for this object look on

[How To Update a SQL Server Database by Using the SqlDataAdapter Object in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308507/en-us)

Comment: Will u plz tell me in detail.. how to achieve this with SqlDataAdapter ? Please support with some code.. thanks in advance

Comment: Its not working yar..! I think it is meant for Console Application, where as myne was windows froms application ..!

Comment: @RavitejA: no relation with a type of application. It's a technology which can be used whenever you need it. What problem you get?

Comment: Table not getting Updated..! I Strictly followed the instructions.. I created dataset using designer window.. in that example Dataset is different.. I tried all possibilities.. BUt no result..!

Comment: My datagridview name is datagridview1 and dataset name is pricedataset... and table name is COST..can u plz edit the code in that MSDN form accordingly to my values..? I m confused with the "CUSTOMERS" there in that form.. what is that?

Comment: @RavitejA: but you don't change annything here, isn't it ?